# java.lang.StackOverflowError from OpenJPA CriteriaQuery using large queries

Tags: derby, openjpa

**Overview**

I'm trying to use an OpenJPA CriteriaQuery to count the number of objects in a DB table that meet certain properties.

I need to be able to apply a filter - to count the number of objects that meet the certain properties only if they have an ID in a known list of IDs.

I am not able to do this if the list is very large.

**Detailed description**

I'm using OpenJPA 2.2.1 with an underlying Derby DB.

My CriteriaQuery is being mapped to an SQL query with a WHERE clause that includes 
`t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? ...`
for each of the known IDs.

This normally works fine.

If this list gets large (e.g. a thousand or more IDs in the list), this fails with a java.lang.StackOverflowError.

**Questions**

- Is there a better way to apply a filter that can scale to any
  arbitrary number of object IDs?
- Is there a way to avoid this error?

*I've included a simplified version of my code below, together with OpenJPA exceptions and derby.log errors that resulted.*

---

A simplified version of my code:

```
Collection<Integer> qids = A_LARGE_SET_OF_INTEGERS;

// prepare a criteria query to count objects that match some parameters
CriteriaQuery<Long> criteria = builder.createQuery(Long.class);
Root<MyObjectType> myrootobj = criteria.from(MyObjectType.class);

// counting the number of qids - a nonunique ID value in MyObjectType
criteria.select(builder.countDistinct(myrootobj.get(MyObjectType_.qid)));

// prepare a filter based on a property of the object
Predicate someProperty = builder.equal(myrootobj.get(MyObjectType_.someattr).get(MyOtherObjectType_.id), somefilterid);

// prepare a filter to limit to objects with an ID in the provided set
Predicate filteredObjects = myrootobj.get(MyObjectType_.qid).in(qids);

// apply the filter
criteria.where(builder.and(someProperty, filteredObjects));

long count = em.createQuery(criteria).getSingleResult();
```

---

The only SQL exception errors I can see are SQLState:XJ001 Error Code:-1

The exception thrown looks like this:

```
  <openjpa-2.2.1-r422266:1396819 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Failed to execute query "null". Check the query syntax for correctness. See nested exception for details.
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:872)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:794)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingQuery.execute(DelegatingQuery.java:542)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:286)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:302)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:330)
    at my.code.that.uses.CriteriaQuery
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor335.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
    at ...
Caused by: org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException: DERBY SQL error: SQLCODE: -1, SQLSTATE: XJ001, SQLERRMC: java.lang.StackOverflowErrorXJ001.U {SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t1.id) FROM SomeObjectType t0 INNER JOIN Something t1 ON t0.SOMETHING_ID = t1.id WHERE (t0.attr = ? AND t1.RUN_ID = ? AND (t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ?) AND t1.qid IS NOT NULL)} [code=-1, state=XJ001]
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.wrap(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:219)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.wrap(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:199)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.access$000(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:59)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator$LoggingConnection.prepareStatement(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:251)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:133)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ConfiguringConnectionDecorator$ConfiguringConnection.prepareStatement(ConfiguringConnectionDecorator.java:140)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:133)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager$RefCountConnection.prepareStatement(JDBCStoreManager.java:1646)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:122)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLBuffer.prepareStatement(SQLBuffer.java:449)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLBuffer.prepareStatement(SQLBuffer.java:429)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SelectImpl.prepareStatement(SelectImpl.java:479)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SelectImpl.execute(SelectImpl.java:420)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SelectImpl.execute(SelectImpl.java:391)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.LogicalUnion$UnionSelect.execute(LogicalUnion.java:427)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.LogicalUnion.execute(LogicalUnion.java:230)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.LogicalUnion.execute(LogicalUnion.java:220)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.SelectResultObjectProvider.open(SelectResultObjectProvider.java:94)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl$PackingResultObjectProvider.open(QueryImpl.java:2070)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.singleResult(QueryImpl.java:1320)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.toResult(QueryImpl.java:1242)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:1007)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:863)
    ... 75 more
```

*Note that I've snipped the SQL query in the ReportingSQLException because it was very long - I removed hundreds of the `OR t1.qid = ?` clauses. There were over a thousand of them.*

---

derby.log contains the following:

```
2013-06-30 01:03:16.279 GMT Thread[DRDAConnThread_36,5,main] (XID = 11562784), (SESSIONID = 23), (DATABASE = /full/path/to/my/db), (DRDAID = NF000001.CE86-507216535478407432{22}), Failed Statement is: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t1.id) FROM SomeObjectType t0 INNER JOIN Something t1 ON t0.SOMETHING_ID = t1.id WHERE (t0.attr = ? AND t1.RUN_ID = ? AND (t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ? OR t1.qid = ?) AND t1.qid IS NOT NULL)
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.OrNode.changeToCNF(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.OrNode.changeToCNF(Unknown Source)
    <snip - over a thousand more lines like these>
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.OrNode.changeToCNF(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.OrNode.changeToCNF(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.OrNode.changeToCNF(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.OrNode.changeToCNF(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.OrNode.changeToCNF(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.AndNode.changeToCNF(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.AndNode.changeToCNF(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.AndNode.changeToCNF(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.AndNode.changeToCNF(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.AndNode.changeToCNF(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.SelectNode.normExpressions(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.SelectNode.preprocess(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DMLStatementNode.optimizeStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.CursorNode.optimizeStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement20.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement30.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement40.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver40.newEmbedPreparedStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAStatement.explicitPrepare(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.parsePRPSQLSTT(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.processCommands(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is DERBY-3876: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-3876

A workaround is to use your JVM's ability to set the thread stack size. For example,
try -Xss=2048k, if your version of Java accepts that flag.

Comment: Good spot! That does look like the reason why Derby is failing to handle the query. I'm still trying to find a way to get OpenJPA to create a different type of query, but this is a useful piece of the puzzle, thank you.

Comment: small correction: it should be -Xss2048k or -Xss2m (for Oracle JVM)

Answer (score 0):

Using OpenJPA and MS SQL Server I had a similar problem with a long list of id's but in OrExpression.initialize. The trick with the stack size given by Bryan Pendleton solved the issue at the OpenJPA side.

However now I am hitting the 2100 parameters limit of sql server.

(perhaps depending on the query) a solution is to split the collection of id's into parts of e.g. 1000. Make a for loop that performs a separate query for each such batch and collects the results.